# Migrating php code from 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I was asked to help getting a website that was running with 5.2 php code, to work on a 5.3 php server. The site is big, and I can't see the errors that would appear normally when a site isn't working.

I've tried to use the Search and replace function that Dream Weaver has, and simply use it all over the website. But the problem is that I only want to replace functions in PHP documents, and not in js files. When i use Search and replace, in Dreamweaver, it overwrites the js files aswell, and that would cause more errors. Because there's A LOT of files that i have to go through, it would take me a lot of time if i had to go through it manually.

I figured this must be a problem that a lot of firms experiance, so there must be ways to handle this without it being a bigger hassle.

Anybody out there who could help me out ? Any help is much appreciated!

Regards,
Mathias

Comment: What exactly are you replacing in the files?

Comment: Why can't you see the errors? Don't you have a php log you can view? Also, have your check [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php)?

Comment: I am replacing all from the deprecative: [link]http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the official guide about [Migrating from PHP 5.2.x to PHP 5.3.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.php)

most existing PHP 5 code should work without changes, but make sure [error-reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is enabled to get some idea of what is going wrong .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the use of sed from command line. It is most likely the fastest and most powerful find/replace utility available for LAMP developers.

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score -1):

Dont worry about it! If your code works in php->5 for the most part it will work just fine.  5.3 offers a plethora of options but no doubt your not using them.